# parse attribute of style from div using simple html dom

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I'm using simple_html_dom (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to parse a code like this:

```
<div class="photo" style="width: 670px; height: 465px; background-image: url('imgurl'); background-position: -15px 0px;"></div>
```

I need to get the `imgurl` value inside of `background-image`. Is it possible? How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why are you using Simple HTML DOM?  I do not understand what you are doing or trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Can you post the php code you have so far using the Simple HTML DOM plugin?

Comment: improved question grammar

Comment: You need a combination of Dom and Regex. Similar questions come up all the time.